# return true actually returns undefined using async

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, node-async

I'm trying to do something if the value is not exist, so I can update it. but isExist function always return undefined. what can I do with this?

reference: `Ero` is already defined.

```
async.forEachOf(idArray, function(value, key, cb) {
    rp(baseURL + value)
      .then(function(json) {
          if (!isExist(json)) {
              // do something
            } else {
                console.log(isExist(json), "It's not video or exists");
            }
        })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    })
    cb();
  }, function() {
    res.status(200)
  });
});

function isExist(data) {
  let parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
  if (parsedData.items[0].type === 'Video') {
    Ero.find({
      videoUri: parsedData.items[0].url_mp4
    }, function(err, docs) {
      if (docs.length) {
          return true;
      } else {
          return false;
      }
    })
  } else {
      return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: A JsFiddle would be nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at your `isExist` function.

```
function isExist(data) {
  let parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
  if (parsedData.items[0].type === 'Video') {
    Ero.find({
      videoUri: parsedData.items[0].url_mp4
    }, function(err, docs) {
      if (docs.length) {
          return true;
      } else {
          return false;
      }
    })
  } else {
      return false;
  }
}
```

In that function you have two branches at the conditional. When the condition is `false` the `else` block will run – this returns `false`. When the condition is `true` the first block will run however **there is no return statement, therefore implicitly returning `undefined`**.

You say **"why does it not have a return statement?"**, **I'm pretty sure I have one**.

It *looks like* you have one here.

```
if (docs.length) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

However look at which function it is returning out of. It is only returning out of the callback function passed to `Ero.find`, it does not return out of `isExist`.

You ask **"what can I do about this?"**.

I am assuming `Ero.find` is an asynchronous function, therefore `isExist` will become an asynchronous function too. To do async functions in JavaScript you can use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Here's some example code of what `isExist` might look like with a Promise.

```
function isExist(data) {
  /**
   * `isExist` returns a Promise. This means the function _promises_ to have a value resolved in the future.
   */
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
    if (parsedData.items[0].type === 'Video') {
      Ero.find({
        videoUri: parsedData.items[0].url_mp4
      }, function(err, docs) {
        if (docs.length) {
          /**
           * Once `Ero.find` has completed, `resolve` `isExist` with a value of `true`, otherwise `resolve` `isExist` with a value of `false`.
           */
          resolve(true);
        } else {
          resolve(false);
        }
      })
    } else {
      /**
       * You can resolve a Promise even without performing an asynchronous operation.
       */
      resolve(false);
    }
  });
}
```

**Further reading**

- [Async & Performance](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/async%20%26%20performance), a book in the series [You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS) by Kyle Simpson.
- [Promises in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
- [Async functions in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Answer (score -1):

Using JSON.parse will put you in a risk to have an exception if the JSON has a syntax error. Use a    try / catch block.

Without knowing your data I cannot say what else is wrong on your check.

```
function isExists(data){
  try{
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
    if (parsedData.items[0].type === 'Video') {
      Ero.find({
        videoUri: parsedData.items[0].url_mp4
      }, function(err, docs) {
        if (docs.length) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      })
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }catch(e) {
    // any error 
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Then post your data.